# Permissions on nginx before launching?

Tags: php, nginx

I've tried searching about this online but found nothing decent. Here is my setup

- NGINX serving php, javascript, css, html, etc
- There is a folder inside web root that ONLY localhost should be able to access. (I've dealt with this permissions via location restriction in nginx directives)

How exactly should I set permissions for **all** folders that are **not** **my web root**? What should their permissions be? For example, **/etc/nginx** and **/usr/whatever**. What commands should I use?

And the content, properly said, which permissions should it have to allow only execution? I've read about 740 or something alike but what is "reading" a php file and "executing" a php file? How exactly should I put it?

And what about ownership of the content and users? How could I put this in root? Any important files I should change in php.ini to avoid malicious intent?

Comment: Your main problem seems to be overthinking stuff.

You shouldn't be touching permissions on `/etc/nginx` and `/usr/whatever`. You don't need to add execution permissions to .php files (they're not being *directly* executed, that's handled by PHP-FPM). What **actual** problem are you having that you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @ceejayoz nothing much, just making sure I'm not forgetting anything crucial before launching the service... What about read permissions? Which permissions should the files have?

Comment: Suggestion: just launch the service, and fix whatever doesn't work. The only permissions I've had to ever tweak for nginx+php has been making folders writeable by nginx when they need to store file uploads from a form. For obvious reasons, nginx needs to be able to read (and if you're putting the files somewhere sensible like `/srv/web` or `/var/www` or something, it will), but it never needs execution privileges, and only needs write privileges to storage/cache directories *if you have them*.